# Unable to resolve GCMReceiver after adding to gradle & libs

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

I've been following SO posts about installing Google Play Services with the SDK manager, ensuring the .jar file is in my package's /libs folder and putting the dependency file in.

I'm still getting unable to resolve errors.

Manifest:

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="mypackage" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

GCMIntentService

cannot resolve symbol GCMBaseIntentService

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should write the class name in android: name. For example, "android: name =". GCMIntentService "or package. ClassName

Comment: Anything using gcm.jar has been deprecated for over a year - it has completely changed at least 3 times over since then. Best to start fresh.